# In vimrc, how can I chain multiple instructions in one Leader command

Tags: vim, vimrc

In my .vimrc I have:

```
map <Leader>c :GitGutterToggle<CR>
map <Leader>n :set invnumber<CR>
```

Is there any way I can combine these two into one Leader entry?

For example:

```
map <Leader>c :GitGutterToggle && :set invnumber<CR>
```

I've tried the above, and variations thereof, to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Try asking on [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7):

Vim uses `|` to chain ex commands. From [`:h cmdline-lines`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-lines):

```
                                                        :bar :\bar
'|' can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one
line.  If you want to use '|' in an argument, precede it with '\'.

These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be
followed by another Vim command:
```

This is followed by a list of commands, which *does not* include `:map` or its variants. So, you'll need to use `\|`.  Further down the help is a note about `:map`, which leads to [`:h map_bar`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map_bar):

```
                                                        map_bar map-bar
Since the '|' character is used to separate a map command from the next
command, you will have to do something special to include  a '|' in {rhs}.
There are three methods:
   use       works when                    example      
   <Bar>     '<' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls <Bar> more^M
   \|        'b' is not in 'cpoptions'     :map _l :!ls \| more^M
   ^V|       always, in Vim and Vi         :map _l :!ls ^V| more^M

(here ^V stands for CTRL-V; to get one CTRL-V you have to type it twice; you
cannot use the <> notation "<C-V>" here).

All three work when you use the default setting for 'cpoptions'.
```

So, assuming you haven't modified `cpoptions`:

```
map <Leader>c :GitGutterToggle <bar> :set invnumber<CR>
```

Note that [you should use `noremap`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2092/205) (and the more specific `nnoremap`, `vnoremap`, etc.) map commands so that you don't surprised by your mappings.

Comment: I was using a literal ("|") character in my ~/.vimrc and it wasn't working. But changing that to ("<bar>") did the trick!